# How to use pymssql with Django?

Tags: sql-server, django, pymssql

This is mssql:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/2.1.3

would I use it on django??

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'pymssql',
    'NAME': 'XXXXX',
    'HOST': 'XXXXX',
    'USER': 'XXXXXXX',
    'PASSWORD': 'XXXXX',
    'PORT': '1433',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
    },
 }

}
```

now i get this error

```
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named 'pymssql'
```

is there anyway to fix it?

thanks a lot

Comment: Install this library pip install django-mssql

Comment: thanks~~ now it works

Comment: but now when I do the " inspectdb" , the model had this "sqlserver_ado.fields.BigAutoField(db_column='ID')"                                            but......it shows NameError: name 'sqlserver_ado' is not defined